# How to make an animation trigger each time the page is scrolled?

Tags: css, animation, scroll, css-animations

I have a very sublet keyframe animation. I'd like for it to play every single time the page has been scrolled - not just once when coming in the viewpoint. Each time the scroll is touched. All I can find is running once in viewport - which is fine, but it needs to play every time the scroll is touched in the viewport. Any ideas?

```
/* CSS */
.aha-section .pixels .light {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 33px;
    animation: slide 2s 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        margin-left: 33px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 45px;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 33px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some JavaScript... then you will listen to the `scroll` event to do the desired function...

To trigger a animation set a class to it:

```
.scrolled .aha-section .pixels .light {
    animation: slide 2s 1;
}
```

and let the javascript add this class when the event `scroll` happens:

`document.body.className += ' scrolled';`

hope it helps to show you the direction.

```js
let animated = false;

window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    animateOnScroll();
});

function animateOnScroll(){
  if(animated == false){
    animated = !animated;
    document.body.className += ' scrolled';  
    setTimeout(function() {
        animated = false;
        document.body.classList.remove('scrolled');
    }, 2000); //match whatever time set on css animation 
  }
}
```

```css
.aha-section {
  position: fixed;
}
.aha-section .pixels .light {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 33px;
}

.scrolled .aha-section .pixels .light {
    animation: slide 2s 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        margin-left: 33px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-left: 45px;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 33px;
    }
}

.scroll-emulator {
  height: 2500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aha-section">
    <div class="pixels">
        <div class="light">Light</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-emulator"><div>
```

Comment: This is PERFECT. Makes total sense & works like a charm. Cannot thank you enough.